# helper_data.php not found in custom module

Tags: module, magento-1, configuration, system.xml, system.log

I have created a new module. But it is showing error on log file like following:

```
2016-09-23T06:03:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/andropls/magento/includes/src/Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/andropls/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-23T06:03:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(/home/andropls/magento/includes/src/Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Helper_Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/andropls/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
2016-09-23T06:03:35+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/andropls/magento/includes/src/Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Helper_Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/andropls/magento/includes/src:.:')  in /home/andropls/magento/includes/src/Varien_Autoload.php on line 94
```

My `config.xml` is like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Envato_Custompaymentmethod>
      <version>1.0.0.0</version>
    </Envato_Custompaymentmethod>
  </modules>
<global>
    <fieldsets>
      <sales_convert_quote_payment>
        <custom_field_one>
          <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
        </custom_field_one>
        <custom_field_two>
          <to_order_payment>*</to_order_payment>
        </custom_field_two>
      </sales_convert_quote_payment>
    </fieldsets>
    <helpers>
      <custompaymentmethod>
        <class>Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Helper</class>
      </custompaymentmethod>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <custompaymentmethod>
        <class>Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Block</class>
      </custompaymentmethod>
    </blocks>    
    <models>
      <custompaymentmethod>
        <class>Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Model</class>
      </custompaymentmethod>
    </models>
    <resources>
      <custompaymentmethod_setup>
        <setup>
          <module>Envato_Custompaymentmethod</module>
        </setup>
      </custompaymentmethod_setup>
    </resources>
  </global>
  <default>
    <payment>
      <custompaymentmethod>
        <active>1</active>
        <model>custompaymentmethod/paymentmethod</model>
        <order_status>pending</order_status>
        <title>CustomPaymentMethod</title>
        <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
        <payment_action>sale</payment_action>
      </custompaymentmethod>
    </payment>
  </default>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <custompaymentmethod>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Envato_Custompaymentmethod</module>
          <frontName>custompaymentmethod</frontName>
        </args>
      </custompaymentmethod>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

and this is `system.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>    
  <sections>
    <payment>
      <groups>
        <custompaymentmethod translate="label" module="custompaymentmethod">
          <label>CustomPaymentMethod Module</label>
          <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
          <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
          <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
          <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
          <fields>
            <title translate="label">
              <label>Title</label>
              <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <sort_order>1</sort_order>
            </title>
            <active translate="label">
              <label>Enabled</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <sort_order>2</sort_order>
            </active>
            <order_status translate="label">
              <label>New order status</label>
              <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_order_status</source_model>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
              <sort_order>3</sort_order>
            </order_status>
            <allowspecific translate="label">
              <label>Payment from applicable countries</label>
              <frontend_type>allowspecific</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_payment_allspecificcountries</source_model>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
              <sort_order>4</sort_order>
            </allowspecific>
            <specificcountry translate="label">
              <label>Payment from Specific countries</label>
              <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
              <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
              <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
              <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
              <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
              <sort_order>5</sort_order>
            </specificcountry>
          </fields>
        </custompaymentmethod>
      </groups>
    </payment>
  </sections>
</config>
```

This is helper file Data.php content:

```
<?php
    class Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{
    }
?>
```

When I disable the `system.xml` file the error is not showing and 'Payment method' option showing correctly in admin. But when I enable the `system.xml` file the error log showing the error message and the 'Payment method' option page showing blank page in admin. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **create the helper** as it will be used in your `system.xml` for translation purpose.

As soon as you write:

```
<custompaymentmethod translate="label" module="custompaymentmethod">
```

The `module` attribute specifies the helper to be used.

All you need to do is create an empty helper class `Helper/Data.php` :

```
<?php

class Envato_Custompaymentmethod_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

}
```

NB: it seems like you have the compiler enabled. **Don't forget to recompile under System > Tools > Compiler** once you've created the helper class.

Comment: I also added helper file like your suggestion

Comment: @SubhajyotiDe don't forget to recompiler under System > Tools > Compiler

Comment: From system >Tools >Complier, should I choose enable/disable or choose "Run Compilation Process"?

Comment: @SubhajyotiDe Run Compilation Process ;)

Answer (score 1):

The mentioned error log is of compiled files. Either disable compilation Or recompile by navigating to `System > Tools > Compiler`